# Jquery Change Table Value Coming from AJAX call

Tags: jquery, ajax

Hi I am building a table with ajax from a response JSON. So, If in my response data there is a price object. If the price is null, I want to show it as 0.

Here is my `AJAX` code -

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

var url ="data/response.json";
var data=""; 
coAjax(url, data, function(result){
  var availableProductsList = result.response.availableProducts;
  var terminalProductsList = result.response.availableProducts;
  console.log(availableProductsList);
  var output="<tbody>";

        for (var i in availableProductsList){ 
           output += "<tr><td>" 
                    + result.response.availableProducts[i].productId + 
                    "</td><td>" 
                    + result.response.availableProducts[i].productName + 
                    "</td><td>" 
                    + result.response.availableProducts[i].quantity + 
                    "</td><td>" 
                    + "<div class='replace-split-key-tbl-inputbox'>" + "<input type='text' class='form-control key-input key-input-tbl' id="+ result.response.availableProducts[i].productId +">" + "</div>" + 
                    "</td><td><span class='availableFeaturesPriceCol'>"+ result.response.availableProducts[i].price +"</span></td></tr>";

        console.log(result.response.availableProducts[i].price);

        }

        output+="</tbody>";
 $("#addfeaturesOrderTbl").append(output);
 $("table").addClass("table");
});
});

function coAjax(url, data, handleData) {
    $.ajax({
    url:url,
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data:JSON.stringify(data),
    success:function(result) {
        handleData(result); 
    }
  });
}
```

For the price column, if the price is null I want to show it as 0. This is the code to get the price `result.response.availableProducts[i].price`. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can  add a [Logical OR (`||`) operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators) after it so if it is falsy it will use zero instead

```
result.response.availableProducts[i].price || 0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var price = result.response.availableProducts[i].price;
price != null ? output+=`<td>${price}</td>` : output+="<td>0</td>";
```

Answer (score 0):

It's

```
var price = result.response.availableProducts[i].price;
           var priceFinal;
           if(price != null){
                priceFinal = price;
           }else{
                priceFinal = 0;
           }
```